# How to select data using sql which not in datagridview

Tags: c#

I am trying to select data (column name `emp_id`) from the database which is not in the datagridview.

For example:

```
Select * 
from employees 
where emp_id <> '"+datagridview.the row emp_id.tostring()+"' ;
```

Comment: **which not in the datagridview** is not good filter for me. be more specific. then you can get help, guess.

Comment: forgive my poor English cause , anyway
I just need a way to get data from database where is not exist in datagridview

Comment: You could get the data before filling the datagridview, then hide the column. That way, once the user select the row, you could read the hidden value.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `datagridview.the row emp_id.tostring()`

try this.

```
string whereClause = "";
if (idsInGrid.Any()) 
{
  whereClause = " WHERE emp_id NOT IN (" + String.Join(",", idsInGrid) + ") ";
}
string query = selectFromQueryPart + whereClause;
```

You use NOT IN to filter out the IDs. Notice that if there are none ids you want to filter out, you simply do not use the where clause.

EDIT:
works for IDs being int. If you use anything else, replace `String.Join(",", idsInGrid)` with `String.Join(",", idsInGrid.Select(id => String.Format("'{0}'", id)))`, which will enclose the text in single quotes.